# How to merge my local project with a github project?

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, github

Some months ago, I downloaded a GitHub project (https://github.com/Unidata/thredds) in order to adapt some parts of the code and to develop it in Eclipse (The creators develop the project in Intellij) and I downloaded the zip file, therefore I didn't clone the repo.

On the other hand, my local project is out of date and I would like to update the local project through the GitHub original project.

Edit:

My project folder includes a .gitignore folder but it does not include a .git folder so there is no reference to the master/original

I've done this:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/Unidata/thredds.git
$ git fetch upstream
remote: Counting objects: 172902, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54837/54837), done.
remote: Total 172902 (delta 106502), reused 172153 (delta 106046)
Receiving objects: 100% (172902/172902), 813.46 MiB | 1.70 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (106502/106502), done.
From https://github.com/Unidata/thredds
 * [new branch]      17gridfc   -> upstream/17gridfc
 * [new branch]      4.5.0      -> upstream/4.5.0
 * [new branch]      4.5.1      -> upstream/4.5.1
 * [new branch]      4.5.2      -> upstream/4.5.2
 * [new branch]      d4test     -> upstream/d4test
 * [new branch]      d4test0    -> upstream/d4test0
 * [new branch]      d4test1    -> upstream/d4test1
 * [new branch]      http43     -> upstream/http43
 * [new branch]      opuls      -> upstream/opuls
 * [new branch]      target-4.3.21 -> upstream/target-4.3.21
 * [new branch]      target-4.3.22 -> upstream/target-4.3.22
 * [new branch]      target-4.3.23 -> upstream/target-4.3.23
 * [new branch]      target-4.4.0 -> upstream/target-4.4.0
 * [new branch]      target-4.4.2 -> upstream/target-4.4.2
 * [new branch]      target-4.4.3 -> upstream/target-4.4.3
 * [new branch]      test3      -> upstream/test3
 * [new branch]      test_framework -> upstream/test_framework
 * [new branch]      try-gradleInitForMaven -> upstream/try-gradleInitForMaven
 * [new branch]      x452       -> upstream/x452
From https://github.com/Unidata/thredds
 * [new tag]         thredds-4.3.10 -> thredds-4.3.10
 * [new tag]         v4.3.11    -> v4.3.11
 * [new tag]         v4.3.12    -> v4.3.12
 * [new tag]         v4.3.13    -> v4.3.13
 * [new tag]         v4.3.14    -> v4.3.14
 * [new tag]         v4.3.15    -> v4.3.15
 * [new tag]         v4.3.16    -> v4.3.16
 * [new tag]         v4.3.17    -> v4.3.17
 * [new tag]         v4.3.18    -> v4.3.18
 * [new tag]         v4.3.19    -> v4.3.19
 * [new tag]         v4.3.20    -> v4.3.20
 * [new tag]         v4.3.22    -> v4.3.22
 * [new tag]         v4.3.8-BETA -> v4.3.8-BETA
 * [new tag]         v4.3.9.alpha1 -> v4.3.9.alpha1
 * [new tag]         v4.4.0     -> v4.4.0
 * [new tag]         v4.4.1     -> v4.4.1
 * [new tag]         v4.4.2     -> v4.4.2
 * [new tag]         v4.5.0     -> v4.5.0
 * [new tag]         v4.5.1     -> v4.5.1
```

I know I have the 4.3.15 in my local folder and I would like to update it to the 4.3 last version and then commit my changes to github without changing the original. Maybe, I have to create a fork or something from my local project but I don't know how to update it properly and commit the changes to my own version.

regards

Comment: Did you download [a release](https://github.com/Unidata/thredds/releases) ? The question about svn should be asked seperately.

Comment: I updated the question. I downloaded a release (4.3.15) version but I don't know why my folder only inclues a .gitignore file. It has not reference to the origin, so I've tried to follow this http://superuser.com/questions/487007/how-to-merge-changes-from-original-project-github-in-windows as my edit shows

Comment: You probably have a lot of work to do for what you're asking, you need to a) move your files somewhere else b) clone and checkout 4.3.15 c) copy and paste your file changes onto that checkout (i.e. so you can manage only your changes on the version you made them to) d) commit your changes e) merge in latest 4.3 f) deal with any conflicts. That would then put you in a position to pull upstream changes, and what you'd have then is an unpublished "fork".

Comment: The step c) is not possible to do with git? @barni commented I can run a diff check. I'm not sure about how many files I changed so it could help if git can do that work for me.

Comment: It is - doing a soft reset or using stash I wrote the above assuming no git knowledge/understanding. Irrespective of what you do it'd be a good idea to guarentee yourself that you can get back to your currently-untracked state.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with these steps:

1) Check out the v4.3.15 branch to a separate directory

2) Run a diff check to check for the differences between the checked out version and your own version.

3) Apply your changes to the checked out branch.

4) Commit your changes locally. Now you have a commit that consists of the changes you made to the 4.3.15 version)

5) Rebase your commit on top of the latest version you are interested in (I suppose it is the 4.3.23).

6) Solve any conflicts that you might have.

7) Commit your changes locally.

8) Push your changes to GitHub.

Comment: Could you help me with some commands? I know how to clone and not much more. Will the diff check properly the differences between a clone and my modified directory which does not have the .git folder?

Comment: Applying the changes to 4.3.15 and then rebasing makes little sense. It seems pretty unlikely thst'd ve conflict-free and isno different than attempting to directly apply local changes to 4.3.23

Comment: @AD7six It might make little sense, but you are making assumptions that you don't know if they are right.


Yes, it is probable that the outcome is the same because it's just a release version change (and you should expect very little change).


But there's nothing wrong in applying the changes to the same version he modified and then rebasing. Otherwise, he might reintroduce bugs by doing it the way you explained.

Comment: What you're implicitly doing in this answer is assuming that `git rebase 4.3.22` will be conflict free, or trivial to resolve - the changes made by mannuk aren't known but it's much safer **not** to rebase, especially for someone who's a new git user. I'm not sure where I said there'd be very little change [this looks pretty big to me](https://github.com/Unidata/thredds/compare/v4.3.15...v4.3.22) **600+ commits** - but it's not a factor in my comment. In short using a workflow which will make conflicts more likely isn't something I think is a good idea or good advice.

Comment: I don't understand what can be the problem if a) git is particularly good in allowing you to revert changes, b) the suggested procedure starts from not working in his solution's directory, but diff'ing it with the checkedout branch, c) rebasing doesn't strike me as a dificult operation or a feature a newbie should avoid using (this always assuming the OP is a newbie) d) he can always do what you suggested as an alternative. Either case's difficulty will depend on what @mannuk changes are in relation to what's changed between his baseline and 4.3.22.